# Can you install floor boards over a polished concrete floor?

Tags: flooring

If the floor is a polished concrete floor and you want to install floorboards is it safe to do so or are there steps that need to be taken first?

I have not decided on the type of floor boards, its the first step and I want to understand the considerations

Comment: What are the floorboards made of?  Are they real hardwood, engineered hardwood, some type of synthetic?

Comment: Most floor boards want a flat surface without any dips or humps.  If you have that, it should be okay.  Type of floor board might make a difference.

Comment: @SteveSh not decided yet, currently investigating the possibility and want to understand what I need to consider and if there is anything I should look out for.

Comment: Floating will be much more practical than nailed boards, for obvious reasons. Glue-down parquet would also work fine.

Comment: Can floorboard be installed without glue and without worrying about volume changes?

Comment: Type of room use is important also.  Some types of flooring better for one room(kitchen, family room) than other room type.

Comment: They make waterproof vinyl flooring that is designed to lay directly on top of concrete.  We wanted to do that, but our floor has a drain so it wasn't flat enough.